# Can I take sealed PC parts in the plane from UK to Morocco?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, morocco

I recently bought PC parts that cost me ￡4500 and I'm a student in UK for almost 3 years and I'm going back to my country which is Morocco in October.

Now i'm wondering if I am allowed to take these sealed PC parts with me, and if am allowed so there any tax should I pay, and if there is how much will be.

Comment: If you bought 4500 GBP worth of PC parts, they are very likely not for your own personal use, are they? Also the fact they are sealed points to an intention to resell. Importing stuff for resale is a business, which in most places (and I'm pretty sure in Morocco as well) requires you to be registered as a business, file accounts, file and pay taxes... This is way beyond the scope of this site. Even if it was for your own personal use, you're way over duty free limits, you will have to declare them on arrival and pay taxes on them.

Comment: no , bought it for my own purpose , i do streaming, so what about if throw the boxes and take these  parts and wrapped them in a towel

Comment: 4500 GBP of hardware for your own purposes? Customs inspectors may have doubts about that. As explained below you’ll have to declare the goods and pay taxes on that amount. Sadly, if you didn’t initiate a tax refund procedure when you bought the stuff you won’t be able to reclaim the VAT you paid in the UK on all that stuff (about 750 pounds).

Answer (score 2):

Like every other country, Moroccan Customs will assess import duty for stuff brought into the country. [This page](https://www.easyship.com/duties-and-taxes-calculator/morocco) - a non-governmental source — suggests that the average duty on electronics is 20% of the value of the item(s) imported. 20% of ￡4500 equals ￡900. I do not know if this is the same duty rate as would be assessed against electronic parts, but it does indicate that Moroccan law sees value in electronic material.

Most countries allow an exemption for a certain value of stuff brought into the county by a returning citizen or resident; this value is exempt from duty. I have no idea if an exempt amount exists under Moroccan law, and if it does, what the exemption amount might be. If the returning traveler carries more than the exempt amount of something, many countries assess duty against the entire amount, not just the amount beyond the exemption.

Customs' job is to assess duty. Upon arrival you will be asked if you have "anything to declare," that is, if you're bringing anything on which duty should be assessed. If you do not declare the items you're bringing in, and they examine your baggage and discover this stuff, then you will have been caught lying. That could result in any or all of these: the assessment of duty, the confiscation of the material, a fine, or a criminal charge against you.

Comment: In most countries the allowance is a maximum under which no tax is paid, and above which tax is paid on the whole amount, not the difference with the allowance.

Comment: I disagree that "tax is paid on the whole amount." Were that the case, exemptions become meaningless.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Like most things involving governments and taxation, it's complicated. For example, for the US [this](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/kbyg/types-exemptions) says the $200 exemption to the US works that way "If you bring back more than $200 worth of dutiable items, or if any item is subject to duty or tax, the entire amount will be dutiable".

Comment: Fair enough, I surrender. I'll edit my answer. Thanks you both.